# How do I specify KexAlgorithms and Cipher?

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I am trying to connect to a server using SFTP protocol

To connect successfully, I had to do the following from the centos terminal.

```
sftp -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=aes256-cbc USER_NAME@IP_ADDRESS
```

Now I want to connect to the same server using SFTP using PHP Curl.

I added the below to curl_setopt

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA');
```

but it is returning error as

```
Failure establishing ssh session
```

How can I specify the KexAlgorithms and Ciphers in PHP curl to connect successfully?

Comment: Yes I tried the following but didnot work.  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA');

Comment: I edited the question to include what i tried

Comment: Added the error also

Comment: <b>SSL</b>_CIPHER_LIST is for SSL (aka TLS) not SSH

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the answer to this for future reference for anyone.

I ended up using Net_SFTP which resolved the issue.